# Power BI - calculate % paid vs expected?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the below 2 tables in my report (they are both joined in an SSAS model using contractID).

Still learning DAX so apologies if I am overcomplicating the below..

[image]

The schedule table tells us for every contract id, how much money we expect to have received at any point in time. So we can see that on the 28th of Jan 2016, we expected to have £233.61 and then on the 1 feb 2019 we expected another £58.4. This needs to be a running total also.. so on the 1 feb 2019 the full total of 292.01 is expected.

The amount paid table below it are all the payments we have had for the contract.. I want to calculate at any point in time what the % payments vs expected was.

So If I was to look at the 1st of feb 2016, I would see a % of 57% as we expected to have 233.61 at that point, and we only had 134.26 (the £200 minus the -65.74)

Ideally I would just be able to see this monthly, so per month year the % of paid vs total expected up to that point.

Does anyone know the best way of achieving this? I am thinking I might need to create an unrelated date table to anchor the measures I will need. But really don't know where I would start with it?

Updated
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put a sample of your data into the model, and it looks as follows

Schedule table

[image]

Payment table

[image]

Add the relation between two tables on *ContractId*.

Then add measures as follows (remember to change the column names respectively):

```
Payment Amount = SUM( AmountPaid[PaymentAmt] )
```

```
Expected Amount = SUM( Schedule[ExpAmnt] )
```

```
Expected Amount Running Total = 
VAR maxPD = MAX( AmountPaid[PaymentDate] )
VAR result = 
    CALCULATE(
        [Expected Amount],
        FILTER(
            Schedule,
            Schedule[ScheduleDate] <= maxPD
        )
    )
RETURN 
    result
```

```
Payment Amount Running Total = 
VAR maxPD = MAX( AmountPaid[PaymentDate] )
VAR minPD = 
    CALCULATE( 
        MIN( AmountPaid[PaymentDate] ),
        ALLSELECTED( AmountPaid )
    )
VAR result =
    CALCULATE(
        [Payment Amount],
        ALL( AmountPaid[PaymentDate] ),
        AmountPaid[PaymentDate] >= minPD,
        AmountPaid[PaymentDate] <= maxPD
    )
RETURN
    result
```

`ALL` and `ALLSELECTED` functions allow you to add a *PaymentDate* slicer to your report. The *Payment Amount Running Total* will be computing dynamically based on that date range selection.

*% of expected Payment* gives you the percentage.

```
% of expected Payment = 
    DIVIDE( [Payment Amount Running Total], [Expected Amount Running Total] )
```

The final result is:

[image]

Note that I am using my native language in the report. So *Rok* is *Year* and *Miesiąc* is *Month*. Months are as follows *Oct, Feb, May, Jun, Aug, Jan, Jul*.

I hope you find it helpful, and it works for you.

Edit:

Add `REMOVEFILTERS` to *Expected Amount Running Total*. In your case, some *ContractIds* have probably no related row in *Schedule* table. The *BLANKS* are occurs then. To prevent that kind of situation, you have to change the context via `CALCULATE` by removing all filters from the main table.

```
Expected Amount Running Total = 
VAR maxPD = MAX( AmountPaid[PaymentDate] )
VAR result = 
    CALCULATE(
        [Expected Amount],
        REMOVEFILTERS(AmountPaid),
        Schedule[ScheduleDate] <= maxPD
    )
RETURN 
    result
```

I've added some additional rows to my sample dataset to *AmountPaid* table only. See the outputs below. The first table is without `REMOVEFILTERS` part.
[image]

Comment: This is really useful, I have never used variables in PBI before. Thank you for this insight!

Comment: I am glad it works for you :) Find more about variables here https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/variables-in-dax/. Note that variables are immutable :)

Comment: I was just testing this and it looks as though if I anchor it by payment date, then I will never see the expected amount unless there is a payment against it?

Comment: What do you mean by anchor it? Are you selecting a specific date on the slicer?

Comment: It just looks like the expected amount running total isn't working as I expected.. please see the screenshot I have attached in the original post. Not sure if I am missing something here?

Comment: I've edited my post. Check the solution. Hope it will solve your problem now.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Just got round to trying this - YES perfect! Thank you for helping with this... I have definitely learned something new!